# Custom mouse-driven transform-style UI/input tool?

Tags: python, add-on, tools

Is there a way to trigger an interactive, mouse-driven input event— Like the built-in `[G]`, `[R]`, `[S]`, `[CTRL]+[R]`, etc. hotkeys— and get the user input in Python?

Comment: ...I suppose I could try overloading, wrapping, parsing the outcomes of, and undoing one of the built-in transform tools, but that'd obviously be bad.

Comment: I think the thing you're looking for is 'Modal Operators'. There are some templates in the Text Editor Templates section that show examples.